# LDAPS and AD DS domain admin remote account creation

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I have written an LDAPS method in Java to create AD accounts. I have found that I can only create accounts if the domain admin account used create them exists within the same OU tree

Domain admins that are in here

- OU=staff,OU=users,OU=TEST_COLLEGE,DC=Company,DC=local

Can create users in here

- OU=students,OU=users,OU=TEST_COLLEGE,DC=Company,DC=local

However, a domain admin in here cannot

- CN=Users,DC=Company,DC=local

Is this normal permission/security behaviour of LDAP/AD?

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not normal behavior. There is likely something wrong with your code. Members of the Domain Admins should be able to create users anywhere.

Comment: Yes, they should do... however this is not happening via LDAPS. It only works if the domain admin is in the same OU tree and not is the domain admins account is in the root Users